# Which is the better choice of word – "govern" or "regulate"?

Tags: contract-law

If I want to talk about what a contract or agreement "does", which is the better verb to use – *govern* or *regulate*?

Examples:

1. The parties' commitments are governed/regulated by this agreement.
2. The parties agree that issues arising from changed circumstances cannot be governed/regulated by this agreement.
3. The supply of services is governed/regulated by this agreement

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the meaning and effect will be the same, and the choice is merely one of style. The word "govern" suggests an overall control, while "regulate" suggests control on the detail level, but in the example used, i don't think there would be any difference of legal effect.

Comment: Thanks again for a prompt and clear answer! :)